# How to bind session values in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, session-variables

I need to bind my session values into my crystal reports using parameter. How can I bind it?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: If you know how to send parameters to the report then where's the problem? If you don't just google a bit...

Answer (score 2):

read this topic

[Programmatically-Pass-Parameters-into-Crystal-Report](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61393/Programmatically-Pass-Parameters-into-Crystal-Repo)

Answer (score 1):

```
report.SetParameterValue("@SessionVar", sessionvar);
```

where: @SessionVar is the parameter you added at the design of the report and sessionvaris the value for the parameter